# Creating an array of numbers without looping?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, jakarta-mail

Okay so I am using the JavaMail library and I am trying to fetch certain message numbers. I want to do it efficiently and not have to loop twice over something… Anyways my question to you is: How can I create an array that starts at index `x` and ends at index `x - 11` without looping?

Comment: You don't need a loop to *create* an int array ;) `int[] array = new int[11];`

Comment: Don't care about efficiency if you just want to store 11 int values in a simple array. Really. Use a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create and populate an array, you have basically three options:

1. Write the values explicitly: `int[] nums = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... }`
2. Use some form of for-loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { nums[i] = i; }`
3. Create it recursively:

```
int[] nums = new int[12];
nums = populate(0, x, nums);

private int[] populate(int index, int x, int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length >= index) {
        return nums;
    } else {
        nums[index] = x - index; // x-0 through x-11
        return populate(index+1, x, nums);
    }
}
```

Vanilla Java, without extra libraries and whatnot, doesn't support a map function which would allow you to specify a function that would somehow auto-generate your values.

Though, I really don't understand why you don't want to use a loop, especially for something trivial like this.

Comment: JavaMail has an option `Folder.getMessages(int [] array)` and it has an option to fetch a single message. Now which one would be more efficient?
1. Looping through and getting each single message 
2.Looping through, making an array of  message numebrs you want to fetch and then calling getMessages(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: If an API offers a bulk fetch as well as an item-by-item fetch than the first is almost always the more efficient call. Imagine a database behind the scenes: It's faster get 11 items in one select then in 11 select operations.

Comment: There's also a getMessages method that takes a start and end message number and returns an array of Message objects.  If the message numbers you're fetching are not contiguous, you might as well fetch a single message as a time since that's what the other methods do internally.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] myArray = new int[] {x, x-1, x-2, x-3, x-4, x-5, x-6, x-7, x-8, x-9, x-10, x-11};
```

Comment: Is there no other way instead of explicitly stating all indices?

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK 8 it's possible to populate an array using streams instead of for loops.

For example, an array of numbers x through x-11 can be generated using [IntStream.iterate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) which applies the specified function to every previous element to obtain the next one, in this case decrement.

```
int x = 55;
int[] arrayOfNumbers = IntStream
       .iterate(x, previousNumber -> --previousNumber)
       .limit(11)
       .toArray();

// Creates an array containing: [55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45]
```