# Quick call to generate array containing number from 0 to N

Tags: java

Simple question here -- mostly about APIs.

I want to iterate through an array in random order.

It is easy enough to:

1. fill a List with the numbers 0 to N
2. shuffle the List with Collections.shuffle
3. Use this shuffled list to guide my array iteration.

However, I was wondering if step 1 (generating the list of numbers from 0 to N) exists somewhere in prewritten code.

For instance, could it be a convenience method in guava's XYZ class??

Comment: It's easy enough to write your own method that does that.

Comment: Agreed, but small convenience methods like Doubles.compare(double d1, double d2) make the code more readable.  And if I can replace a for loop AND learn about a potentially useful batch of convenience methods that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing in Guava would be

```
ContiguousSet.create(Range.closedOpen(0, n), DiscreteDomains.integers())
```

...but, frankly, it *is* probably more readable just to write the `for` loop yourself.

Comment: Thx.  The little things in Guava have been truly helpful.  That's part of the reason I asked -- in case there was a additional batch of little "readability methods" that I didn't know about.

Comment: There are some cases where the Guava devs might consider things to be "anti-readability methods," and I suspect this might be one such case.

Answer (score 1):

Noting specifically your emphasis on 'quick', I can't imagine there'd be much quicker than

```
List<Integer> = new ArrayList<Integer>(range);
```

and then iterating and populating each entry. Note that I set the capacity in order to avoid having the list resize under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the `Apache Commons` which among many other usefull functions, implement the [nextPermutation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html#nextPermutation%28int,%20int%29) method in `RandomDataGenerator` class

This is obviously something much bigger then a method of populating the `List` or `array`, but commons are really powerfull libraries, which give much more good methods for mathematical computations.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow you to auto-populate your values.  See this question for the ways to populate an array in java

"[Creating an array of numbers without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964622/creating-an-array-of-numbers-without-looping)"

Answer (score -1):

If you skip step 1 and just do the shuffeling immediately I think you will have the fastest solution.

```
int range = 1000;
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(range);
for(int i=0;i<range;i++) {
    arr.add((int)(Math.random()*i), new Integer(i));
}
```